# windows store app gridview customizations?

Tags: gridview, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App GridView which is bound to a collection through ItemsSource property. The collection has 5 items.By default, the items are displayed vertically  like this

Item1 item3 item5
Item2 item4

Is there a way to display the items horizontally and specify how many items to display in a row like this?

Item1 item2 
Item3 item4 item5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinRT there's not particular Row or Column count which can be specified to `GridView`'s `ItemsPanelTemplate` here `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, but there's `MaximumRowsOrColumns` which depends upon `Orientation` property of `VariableSizedWrapGrid`.

The below code demonstrates both the output.

XAML Code

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView x:Name="MyGv" Height="200" Width="650">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Height="50" Width="200" Background="Gray">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
    <GridView x:Name="MyGv1" Height="200" Width="650" Grid.Row="1">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Height="50" Width="200" Background="Gray">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

C# Code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var ObserControl = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};
    MyGv.ItemsSource = ObserControl;
    MyGv1.ItemsSource = ObserControl;
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

as [Xyroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230188/xyroid) suggested, having two GridViews can solve the issue. Just made some modifications to achieve the desired result.

xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView x:Name="MyGv" Margin="0"  Grid.Row="0" Width="650">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Height="50" Width="200" Background="Gray">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
    <GridView  x:Name="MyGv1" Margin="0" Height="60" Width="650" Grid.Row="1">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Height="50" Width="200"  Background="Gray">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

c#:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        var ObserControl = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        MyGv.ItemsSource = ObserControl.Take(2);
        MyGv1.ItemsSource = ObserControl.Skip(2);
    }
```